# How to connect database in neoclipse?

Tags: eclipse, neo4j, graph-databases, neoclipse

I created a database in Neo4j via eclipse. How to view this database on neoclipse? I've seen some tutorials but I don't understand. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would point neoclipse to the data directory on disk or to the server http URL that hosts your data.

Probably easier to copy your database directory contents to a neo4j-server's `/path/to/neo/data/graph.db`